# Unable to load custom pretrained weight in Pytorch Lightning

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I want to retrain a custom model with my small dataset. I can load the pretrained weight (.pth) and run it in Pytorch. However, I need more functionalities and refactored the code to Pytorch lightning but I can't figure out how to load the pretrained weight into the Pytorch Lightning model.

Please see the details of my code below:

```
class BDRAR(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(BDRAR, self).__init__()
        resnext = ResNeXt101()
        self.layer0 = resnext.layer0
        self.layer1 = resnext.layer1
        self.layer2 = resnext.layer2
        self.layer3 = resnext.layer3
        self.layer4 = resnext.layer4
```

Pytorch Lightning code:

```
class liteBDRAR(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super(liteBDRAR, self).__init__()
        self.model = BDRAR()
        print('Model Created!')

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.model(x)
```

Pytorch Lightning run:

```
    path = './ckpt/BDRAR/3000.pth'
    bdrar = liteBDRAR.load_from_checkpoint(path,  strict=False)
    trainer = pl.Trainer(fast_dev_run=True, gpus=1)
    trainer.fit(bdrar)
```

Error:

```
keys = model.load_state_dict(checkpoint["state_dict"], strict=strict)
**KeyError: 'state_dict'**
```

I will appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be that your `.pth` file is already a `state_dict`. Try to load pretrained weight in your lightning class.

```
class liteBDRAR(pl.LightningModule):
    def __init__(self):
        super(liteBDRAR, self).__init__()
        self.model = BDRAR()
        print('Model Created!')

    def load_model(self, path):
        self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path, map_location='cuda:0'), strict=False)

path = './ckpt/BDRAR/3000.pth'
model = liteBDRAR()
model.load_model(path)
```

Comment: This is the error I get when I try that:   `self.model = torch.load_from_dict(torch.load(path), strict=False)
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'load_from_dict'`

Comment: sorry, I update the function. It should be `load_state_dict`.

Comment: Here is the error I get: `AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'load_state_dict'`

Comment: my fault again :( use `self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path), strict=False)` instead. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and got a different error this time:    `RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on CUDA device 1 but torch.cuda.device_count() is 1. Please use torch.load with map_location to map your storages to an existing device.`

Comment: Great, seems we are on the right track. This means you trained the model on the second GPU "GPU 1" (the first one is GPU 0) but now you try to load it from a different environment with only one GPU. 
Use `self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path), strict=False, map_location='cuda:0')`. Check details here https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.load.html#torch.load

Comment: Many thanks @joe32140, I appreciate it. I will try that. I downloaded the model from a repository.

Comment: Same error: `RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on CUDA device 1 but torch.cuda.device_count() is 1. Please use torch.load with map_location to map your storages to an existing device.`

Comment: It should be in torch.load(). `self.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path, map_location='cuda:0'), strict=False)`. Sorry again :(

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting this error is because you are trying to load your PyTorch's model weights into the Lightning module. When saving checkpoints with Lightning you don't only save the model states but also a bunch of other info (see [here](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common/weights_loading.html#checkpoint-saving)).

What you are looking for is the following:

```
path = './ckpt/BDRAR/3000.pth'
bdrar = liteBDRAR()
bdrar.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path))
```

Comment: Many thanks! I will try this and let you the result.

Comment: I get this error:  `RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on CUDA device 1 but torch.cuda.device_count() is 1. Please use torch.load with map_location to map your storages to an existing device.`

Comment: Well the issue is not related to this anymore. I suggest you have a look [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/saving_loading_models.html#saving-loading-model-across-devices)

Comment: Thank you @Jules!

Answer (score 0):

Those pretrained weights belong to `class BDRAR(nn.Module)`. That is, the class in your lightningmodule's `model` param.

The LightningModule `liteBDRAR()` is acting as a wrapper to your Pytorch model (located at `self.model`). You need to load the weights onto the pytorch model inside your lightningmodule.
As @Jules and @Dharman mentioned, what you need is:

```
path = './ckpt/BDRAR/3000.pth'
bdrar = liteBDRAR()
bdrar.model.load_state_dict(torch.load(path))
```

Comment: Thank you @Sarita. I got a runtime error when I tried the suggestions of Jules and Dharman. The last suggestion from joe32140 worked.